# Error for loading driver for Java derby?

Tags: java, derby

I'm wondering why I can't do the simplest step in java database program! I have done this many times before and this time I'm doing seam routine but it doesn't work.

I'm trying to create a database in embedded mode. I have located the derby.jar file in the seam directory. Here is the code and after that is the error:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

     String driver ="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
     String url= "jdbc:derby:MyDatabase";

     try {

        Class.forName(driver).newInstance(); 

    } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+";create=true");   
}
```

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at Data.main(Data.java:16)
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:MyDatabase;create=true
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    at Data.main(Data.java:27)
```

Comment: It seems you have wrong jar in classpath.

Comment: Use IDE, add derby.jar in library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because class path is not configured :

To use Derby in its embedded mode set your CLASSPATH to include the jar files listed below:

> Windows: C:> set
>   CLASSPATH=%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derby.jar;%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derbytools.jar;.
>
> UNIX: $ export
>   CLASSPATH=$DERBY_INSTALL/lib/derby.jar:$DERBY_INSTALL/lib/derbytools.jar:.

http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html#derby_configure